# error messages isn't sended while using two dto class together

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a scope dto class:

```
export class UpdateProgramScopeDto {
  @Matches(scopeTypeRegex)
  @ApiProperty({
    type: String,
    description: 'scopeType',
    enum: SCOPE_TYPE,
  })
  scopeType: SCOPE_TYPE;
}
```

and what to use that in another class:

```
export class RegisterProgramDto {
  @IsArray()
  @ValidateNested({ message: 'd' })
  @Type(() => UpdateProgramScopeDto)
  @ApiProperty({
    type: UpdateProgramScopeDto,
    description: 'scopes',
    isArray: true,
  })
  scopes: UpdateProgramScopeDto[];
}
```

but error messages of scope class isn't sended
how can I fix that?

```
@Post()
  async registerProgram(
    @Body(ValidationPipe) registerProgramDto: RegisterProgramDto,
    @User() user: AuthEntity,
  ) {
    return await this._programService.registerProgram(
      user.user_id,
      registerProgramDto,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to add `each: true` inside ValidateNested: `@ValidateNested({ each: true })`?

Comment: yes, but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you need to **validate an array of objects**, use `each: true` in `@ValidateNested({ each: true })`.

In NestJS you also require the `Type` from `class-transform`. This is a working example:

```js
export class Foo {
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => Bar)
  posts: Bar[];
}
```

Comment: Do you get errors for details in general?

Comment: @samansalehian My example is fully working: https://git.io/JE9MA Are you sure your ValidationPipe is active? `.. @Body(ValidationPipe) ...`

Comment: yes i have actived that but doesn't work.

Comment: @samansalehian Can you add your controller to the post + the request you are sending?

Comment: What request are you sending which is causing the issue with the DTO?

Comment: {
  "scopes": [
    {
      "scopeType": "xxxx",
      "domain": "string",
      "lowPayment": 0,
      "mediumPayment": 0,
      "highPayment": 0,
      "criticalPayment": 0
    }
  ],

Comment: @samansalehian What is scopeTypeRegex and SCOPE_TYPE? The validation is getting called in your example. Did you test it with a simple number check or something?